# Helm chart cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field Volume.spec.template.spec.volumes.configMap

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

```
Reason: Failed to Install Helm Chart [ fk-m3-matching-engine-cache-service:1.4.6 ] =\u003e cannot patch \"matching-engine-cache-service\" with kind Rollout: admission webhook \"webhook-svc.webhook.svc\" denied the request: unmarshal raw request object to rollout failed: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field Volume.spec.template.spec.volumes.configMap of type v1.ConfigMapVolumeSource\n","severity":0}
```

cfg-config.yml -->

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:  
name: cs-config  
namespace: {{ .Values.metadata.namespace }}
data:   
 cfg-api: |+
    host=10.83.47.156
```

I am not sure why this file is throwing error. Consider me a noob in kube, the data `host=10.83.47.156` should be printed in the `cfg-api` file.

Comment: Also tried the same with `host={{ .Values.configHost }}` but the same error

Comment: The error message implies some sort of admission webhook; are you trying to develop this, or is it something an administrator has installed in your cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but **data: cfg-api** is not with proper indentation

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  cfg-api: |-
    host=10.83.47.156
```

Instead of host set the helm template properly